# Use different swift file for different target?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-extensions

There are two target for one project. One is main application project and other is share extension project. I had require to use swift bridge header file in both project

I am facing issue for using different file for different target.

```
#ifndef AMESSAGE_EXTENSION
#import "aMessageAction-Swift.h"
#else
#import "aMessenger-Swift.h"
```

I had taken AMESSAGE_EXTENSION macro in extension project in Other C flags.

I am getting following error while compile.

```
'aMessageAction-Swift.h' file not found
'aMessenger-Swift.h' file not found
```

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: please check your setting in project setting[image]

Step 2: Define module set true
[image]

Step 3: build your project

Step 4: import your xxx-Swift.h in **.m** file <= please check this.